# RubyMine ARGV Parameters

Tags: ruby, rubymine

Does anyone know how to access the `ARGV` values in RubyMine?

I want to work within RubyMine...but can't seem to use `ARGV` when trying to build within RubyMine.  The application works fine in Terminal on my Mac, but not in RubyMine.

This is what I am trying to run in RubyMine, and what I am getting back when built. (Down at the bottom)

[image]

This is what I am supposed to be getting back when built.

[image]

Where do I type the command line arguments in RubyMine?

Comment: To whomever wanted to close this:  RubyMine is a tool used in Ruby development, and thus falls in scope on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RubyMine, the arguments go into the Run/Debug configurations.  You can get there from Run > Edit Configurations.

You should see something that looks like this:

[image]

Be sure to hit Apply after you've filled in the values you want.

Then when you run your script, you'll see the values passed into `ARGV`.

Comment: @JoshuaSforzin:  [You should read up on this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers); saying "thanks" is nice, but accepting an answer is important too.